# Visual Basic (vb.net): Get details of video file eg. frame width

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, shell32, shell32.dll

I am using the shell32.dll to retrieve extended properties of a file. My textbox will display every property of the file (iCollumn -1 to 300) but it won't show the framewidth or frameheight (and many other properties).

Is there any way to get these using shell32.dll? If not, is there an alternate method to get these missing properties?

Notes: I have extensions shown in Windows Explorer, my project is referencing Microsoft shell controls and automation.

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objShell As Shell32.Shell
    Dim objFolder As Shell32.Folder

    objShell = New Shell32.Shell
    objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\Users\Sam\Videos")

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objFolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem
        objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("Kick_Ass.avi")

        If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
            Dim szItem As String
            szItem = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 168)
        End If


        For i = -1 To 300
            TextBox1.Text += i & “: ” & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i) & vbCrLf
        Next


        objFolderItem = Nothing
    End If

    objFolder = Nothing
    objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output (for the sake of space i have only displayed the results that didn't display):

```
-1: Item type: VLC media file (.avi)
Size: 1.36 GB
Length: 01:52:53
Availability: Available offline
0: Kick_Ass.avi
1: 1.36 GB
2: VLC media file (.avi)
3: 10/05/2010 12:49 AM
4: 11/02/2016 1:59 PM
5: 11/02/2016 1:59 PM
6: A

8: Available offline
9: Video
10: Sam-PC\Sam
11: Video

19: Unrated

27: 01:52:53
28: ‎384kbps
29: No

50: 930 GB

54: SAM-PC (this PC)

157: .avi
158: Kick_Ass.avi

162: 813 GB

180: No

183: Videos
184: C:\Users\Sam\Videos
185: Videos (C:\Users\Sam)

187: C:\Users\Sam\Videos\Kick_Ass.avi

189: VLC media file (.avi)

246: ‎12% 

286: Sam-PC\HomeUsers
287: Shared
288: Available
```

Answer (score 0):

The video frame width is at index `i = 316` (this will contain a value like 1920, for example).

The video frame height is at index `i = 314` (this will contain a value like 1080, for example).

The index for possible `objFolderItem` details seems to go as high as `i = 320`.